# I clicked the interested button on Careers to view the hidden phone number and now I can't reply

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, jobs

I don't want to make a phone call but apparently that's all I can do.  I clicked what was essentially the "Continue" button and now I don't have any way to contact this guy except for his phone number and I have zero desire to make a phone call.  Talk about a major flaw.

UPDATE: Since I started writing this he emailed me directly, apparently he gets my email address but I don't get his.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, the system is designed so that companies court you, not the other way around.

Think of it as a dating service -- once the initial "OK, this looks interesting" green light is lit, the rest of the conversation is direct between you and the employer via email.

Comment: Lame.  Forcing me to sit on my hands makes me sad.